# JavaFX KeyEvents during Drag & Drop operation

Tags: java, javafx

I need to know whether a certain key is down while performing a drag & drop operation.

So I tried to use `setOnKeyPressed` / `setOnKeyReleased` of a Scene with a combination of HashMap, but I have a problem with this approach:

Imagine a scenario that one drags & drops a TableView item to somewhere while holding Control down. Now if I *display a dialog at the end of the drop*, while still holding Control down, the `setOnKeyReleased` is never called with this approach... as the Dialog is the one receiving the key released event.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Can you add more context about what you're trying to do (maybe provide a [mcve])? Depending on your goals you may not even have to deal with `KeyEvent`s.

Comment: Well, I'm implementing simply (file) Move & Copy actions in a TableView. If the user drags a table-item to another with holding CTRL down, a copy is performed - move otherwise. And I show a dialog right on the setOnDragDropped(), which, I assume, "steals" the key released event that I have set on the main-scene. I just need to query the state of CTRL somehow within setOnDragDropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I understand your question here is a possible solution(work with any key):

```
public class Main extends Application {
    SimpleBooleanProperty isKeyPress = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent window = new VBox();
        ((VBox) window).getChildren().add(new Label("example of small window:"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("example");
        Scene scene=new Scene(window);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Press");
                isKeyPress.set(true);
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
                alert.setHeaderText(null);
                alert.setContentText("I have a great message for you!");
                Scene alertScene = alert.getDialogPane().getScene();
                alertScene.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                        System.out.println("Released on dialog");
                        isKeyPress.set(false);

                    }
                });
                alert.showAndWait();
            }
        });
        scene.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Released");
                isKeyPress.set(false);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

output exmple:

```
Press
Released on dialog
```

Comment: Sorry it looks like you misunderstood me :/ Check out the comment on the main post for clarification.

Comment: I think it answers your question, you need isKeyPress var and register to the event of KeyReleased on the dialog then you can check the value of isKeyPress , or I Still miss something?

Comment: if you just need the fire of the event the Scene alertScene = alert.getDialogPane().getScene();
                alertScene.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {} will do the mejic for you...

Comment: You're right, sorry! I scanned through the code and thought it did something different... It does indeed solve the exact problem. Not perhaps the most elegant way to solve this problem, but I can live with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52623505/javafx-keyevents-during-drag-drop-operation?noredirect=1#comment92203121_52623505) the goal is to change the behavior of the drag and drop depending on whether or not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is down. When it is do a copy operation, otherwise do a move operation. You do not need to deal with `KeyEvent`s to implement this behavior. Instead, you would determine whether to copy or move in the `onDragDetected` handler. The `onDragDetected` handler uses a [`MouseEvent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html) which has methods for querying the status of modifier keys—such as [`isControlDown()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html#isControlDown()). Using this, we can specify what transfer modes are allowed based on the modifier keys.

```
Node node = ...;
node.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
    Dragboard board;
    if (event.isControlDown()) {
        board = node.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY);
    } else {
        board = node.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
    }
    // add contents to Dragboard
});
```

<sup>Note it may be more cross-platform to use [`isShortcutDown()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html#isShortcutDown()).</sup>

Comment: Ah, so setOnDragDetected has a different type of event than the other setOnDragXYZ methods. I was attempting to do the logic on setOnDragDropped, which does not have isControlDown method on it's event. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `onDragDetected` uses a `MouseEvent` while all the other `onDragXXX` (different from `onMouseDragXXX`) handlers use `DragEvent`. And `DragEvent` is not a subclass of `MouseEvent`.